# Why does "std::string(blablabla());" compile without errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, compiler-errors

Why does the following code compile without warnings. Notice that *blablabla()* is not defined anywhhere.

I tested it in `gcc 5.1.0` and `clang-3.7.0` (with and without the *-std=c++11* flag).

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string(blablabla());
}
```

This questions is **not** a duplicate of the *most vexing parse* ambiguity, since related examples declare functions with a parameter.

Comment: If I were to wager a guess, the statement is optimized out, because you simply aren't using it in any way. You aren't assigning the string to a variable nor are you passing it to a function. As such the compiler may well be 'overlooking' it. But that's a guess.

Comment: Warnings should be independent of *any* optimization, in any recent compiler.

Comment: Err, if `blablabla()` were a function that does `cout << "Hello\n";`, how would that optimisation work out then? I'm pretty certain you're not allowed to optimise code in such a way that it fundamentally changes the behaviour. In any case, it's not actually *calling* `blablabla`, there's no difference between that statement and one with the outer parentheses removed.

Comment: Maybe you simply need to enable more warnings? Try adding `-Wall` when building (something you should do always anyway).

Comment: `-Wall` does not make any difference.

Comment: Isn't `std::string(blablabla());` the same as `std::string  blablabla();`?

Comment: @Bo Persson: I made some experiments, and it seems you are right. I can even define a function as: `std::string(blablabla()){return "x";}`. But what kind of syntax is this? Never saw this before anywhere.

Comment: @oo_miguel - It is standard C declaration syntax. Sometimes the `()` are needed, like when making a pointer to function `int (*f)();` different from a function returning a pointer `int*  f();`. Using extra `()` is *allowed* even when not strictly needed, as that made the language description simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @Bo Persson So in my example the compiler simply ignores the extra parentheses. This makes sense, thank you!

Comment: `std::string(blablabla()){return "x";}` is a nested function, which is not part of Standard C++, but g++ has them

Comment: Compare: `std::string (*blablabla(void));` This just don't have the `*` and the `void` is implicit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahhhh I'm dumb.

It's not treated as a call. The compiler just sees it as a declaration...

Try, for comparison:

```
int main() {
    int(blablabla);
}
```

This gives:

```
test.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c++:6:9: warning: unused variable ‘blablabla’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int(blablabla);
         ^
```

More precisely, your statement `std::string(blablabla())` declares `blablabla` to be a function returning an `std::string`, the same as

```
std::string blablabla();
```

would do. A local function declaration.

Comment: Is int(blablabla); the same as the declaration int blablabla; ?

Comment: Ramana: Yes, you just parenthesed the identifier. Insert a space and it will be clearer: `int ((((blablabla))));`. Btw, there are also cases where the parentheses are even necessary, namely when declaring funtion pointers (to attach the star to the identifier and not the return type).

Comment: @Ramana Yes, the clue is that it warns that the variable `blablabla` is not being used.